# How I can add some text to these picture android

Tags: java, android

how I can write some Text in this picture, i would add some informations.

```
YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, maxwidth, maxheight, null);
Rect rectangle = new Rect();
rectangle.bottom = maxheight;
rectangle.top = 0;
rectangle.left = 0;
rectangle.right = maxwidth;
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compressToJpeg(rectangle, 95, output);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant **add some text** to an image is to add **EXIF** information,
then you can take a look at this link :
[Write/Geotag JPEGs (EXIF data) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531544/write-geotag-jpegs-exif-data-in-android)

If you ment to **draw some text** on the image, then the following may help : 
Put the following code after `image.compressToJpeg(rectangle, 95, output);`.
It's recommended that change this line to `image.compressToJpeg(rectangle, 100, output);` for better image quality when drawing.

```
// Decode the JPEG byte array from 'output' to 'Bitmap' object
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(output.toByteArray(), 0, output.size());

// Use 'Canvas' to draw text ont 'Bitmap'
Canvas cv = new Canvas(bmp);

// Prepare 'Paint' for text drawing
Paint mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setColor( Color.RED );
mPaint.setStyle( Style.STROKE );
mPaint.setTextSize(20);

// Draw text on the 'Bitmap' image
cv.drawText("TEXT To SHOW", 10, 10, mPaint);

// Reset the stream of 'output' for output writing.
output.reset();

// Compress current 'Bitmap' to 'output' as JPEG format
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, output);
```

Then, you can use **output** to do anything you need.