# change metadata of an image in android

Tags: android, image, metadata

How can I put and get some numeric value on metadata on an jpeg image on android .More specifically I want to put and get position (longitude and latitude ) of a place using google map V2 on an image so that later i can recognize where the image is taken.

Comment: These answers are very helpful 
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531544/write-geotag-jpegs-exif-data-in-android>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know later where the image was taken, I suggest you do some kind of a database or SharedPreferences to store the image id and the lat,lng of where it was taken

Comment: Thanks , but in some purpose , i think it will be more effective than shared Preferences or sq-lite   for my project .

Comment: How about you just encode Image with Base64 and add a tail of information you want, and when trying to decode Image, you substring the last tail added. You can put some kind of a tag that marks the end of the encoded image and the beginning of your information