# How can i capture Image along with Latitude and Longitude in their properties in android

Tags: android, geolocation, image-capture, android-gps, geotagging

I would like to capture a image ,and also embed GPS coordinates of that location in to that captured image properties.
Or

Please suggest me in what way it can be achievable or possible that answer also helpful. 
If any better ways also helpful. Thankq in advance.

Comment: Try this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531544/write-geotag-jpegs-exif-data-in-android

Comment: Thankq so much Akshay Panchal .helps me